# Is there an alternative to C# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in Java?

Tags: c#, java, localization

Is there an alternative to C# `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in Java? If not what is the best place to store user selected locale in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Locale.setDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29) sets the default locale for the whole JVM, which is fine for a client application. For a web application, it's not a valid solution, but a thread-local is not either, since the same threads are used for all the users. In this case, the user locale is typically stored in the HTTP session.

Comment: Acutally for a web app the thread local IS - a thread is only handling one user request at a time. It just must be re-initialized in the processng start for the user. THis is how asp.net does it - it evaluates it (from the cookines the brokwser sends), then sets the agreed upon for the thread for this request.

Comment: Agreed. You may store it in a thread-local if you reinitialize its value at each request. Whci means it must be stored elsewhere: in the session, in a cookie or in the database (unless you use the local found in the request, of course)

Answer (score 1):

If you have web SpringMVC based web application there's this class `org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder` ([javadoc here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html)), which gives you access to the current locale.

In webapplication this may be initialized on the basis of `accept-language` request header ([javadoc here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.html)) in `DispatcherServlet`.